# Show hidden partion on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, filemanager

My Ubuntu 14.04 installation doesn't show one of the Partitions(`/dev/sda11`). It contains around 10 GB data, which I can't access.
[image: Screen shot from terminal]

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on

/dev/sda11      19553560 10074608   8462632  55% /mnt
```

Comment: Why is /mnt/ a partition?  That should be a directory containing mountpoints for internal hard disks.

Comment: Can you clarify your question ? /dev/sda11 is mounted at /mnt , it is not hidded. Also please copy-paste from the terminal using the code "{}" for formatting rather than posting screen shots.

Comment: copy-paste from the terminal using the code "{}"  removes formatting. ie table structure.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -la /mnt` ?

Answer (score 0):

The partition is not hidden is is currently mounted at `/mnt`. Btw why did you mount it on `/mnt` just mount it on a folder inside the `mnt` folder. Anyway the files inside the folder maybe hidden so just run `ls -a` or press **CTRL + H** to view hidden files using Thunar or Nemo. Try **Gnome Disk Utility** its great for managing mounting points without using terminal.